# How to avoid the side effects of Intel turbo boost in benchmark?

Tags: java, microbenchmark, jmh

I am running a micro-benchmark with [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) to evaluate the performance of different Java algorithm implementations. Yet, I observe inconsistent throughput depending on weather the Intel CPU turbo boost is running, or not. Since turbo boost is activated according to environment conditions, sometimes it is activated for some bench tests and not for others. Thus, some results show better throughput just because the turbo boost was activated and not because of its better efficiency.

So, I am trying to avoid the effects of turbo boost by annotating all my tests with `@GroupThreads(threadsNumber)` and a `threadsNumber` equals to the number of available processors and thus expect to run all processors in full charge and activate the turbo boost during entire benchmark execution.

Is this a right approach? Is there a more reliable alternative to avoid the effects of turbo boost?

**Updated**: according to @Andreas [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43787629/1140754), an alternative approach is to turn turbo boost off in the BIOS, or in Operating System settings. However, since the CPU clock frequency may change I think that is not enough to turn it off, because the CPU speed variation will affect the benchmarks too. So, maybe it is more reliable to keep it on, force turbo boost to run and set all threads to the benchmark.

Which one would be the better approach to avoid the effects of turbo boost?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent Turbo Boost, turn it off in the BIOS, or in Operating System settings.

Google [`disable turbo boost`](https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+turbo+boost) for how, depending on your system.

Comment: Since the CPU clock frequency may change I think that it is not enough turning it off, because the CPU speed variation will affect the benchmarks result too. So, maybe it is more reliable keeping it on, forcing turbo boost and execute all physical threads in the benchmark.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa Ehhhh, isn't [Turbo Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) *specifically* the dynamic changing of the clock frequency? Are there two different mechanisms in play at the same time for changing CPU clock frequency??? If so, just turn the other one off too. Only way to *guarantee* a steady clock frequency.

Answer (score 0):

I would do graded benchmarks which is what I have done in the past. So you run a single thread and just add a thread in at a time and have benches for example thread count of 1,2,3,4.
Be careful when using the thread pool but instead maybe create raw threads or tag thread pool "Long Running" in the pool to avoid the Hill Climbing Algorithm getting in the way (although with thread count under processor count that shouldn't happen - in theory).

I have graphed this in the past to see the "tail off" as the processor count grows as this gives a far more accurate picture of what is going on.
I would also mix your benchmarks to have purely arithmetic unit work, large memory work and level 1/2 cache work.